# Laravel mpdf does not work after updating PHP from version 5 to 7.3.1

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5, mpdf

After updating PHP on the server to version 7.3.1 and mpdf to version 8, pdf is not generated.
Folders attributes for mpdf -> 755

Code:

```
use Mpdf\Mpdf;
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/assets/temp']);
$pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$pdf->SetProtection(array('print'));
$stylesheet = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/css/invoice.css');

$pdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$pdf->WriteHTML($html_invoice,2);
$pdf_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/invoices/'.$invoice_id.'_'.$this->getPaymentSessionId().'.pdf';
$pdf->Output($pdf_path,"F");
```

is there anything else that needs to change from version 7?

composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.3",
    "alaouy/youtube": "^2.2",
    "anhskohbo/no-captcha": "3.*",
    "anlutro/l4-settings": "^0.4.6",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0",
    "components/jquery": "^3.3",
    "components/jqueryui": "^1.12",
    "danielstjules/stringy": "^3.1",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
    "hashids/hashids": "^3.0",
    "hazestudio/laravel-gopay-sdk": "^0.1.5",
    "illuminate/support": "5.7.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3",
    "jenssegers/agent": "^2.5",
    "kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2": "^1.0.0",
    "laracasts/presenter": "^0.2.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^5.7.0",
    "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.1",
    "league/fractal": "^0.16.0",
    "mpdf/mpdf": "^8.0",
    "nesbot/carbon": "2.0.0-beta2 as 1.26.3",
    "paragonie/random_compat": "~1.4",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation": "2.3.*",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0-rc.3",
    "webpatser/laravel-countries": "dev-master"
```

try to downgrade to 7.1.7 mpdf version:

```
composer require mpdf/mpdf 7.1.7
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for mpdf/mpdf 7.1.7 -> satisfiable by mpdf/mpdf[v7.1.7].
- Conclusion: remove setasign/fpdi v2.2.0
- Conclusion: don't install setasign/fpdi v2.2.0
- mpdf/mpdf v7.1.7 requires setasign/fpdi 1.6.* -> satisfiable by setasign/fpdi[1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2].
- Can only install one of: setasign/fpdi[1.6.0, v2.2.0].
- Can only install one of: setasign/fpdi[1.6.1, v2.2.0].
- Can only install one of: setasign/fpdi[1.6.2, v2.2.0].
- Installation request for setasign/fpdi (locked at v2.2.0) -> satisfiable by setasign/fpdi[v2.2.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\public\info.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\public\info.php on line 6
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Error messages? Checked the web servers error log?

Comment: Which version of mpdf are you using? make sure it's satisfy the requirements of mpdf. see here https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf#php-versions-and-extensions

Comment: @skndrkhtr5 does my Composer.json have everything needed?

Comment: @novice Yes, your composer.json file should've `"mpdf/mpdf": "^8.0",` then this package will have it's own composer.json file which contains the package dependencies. if you're using laravel then why are you using autoloading `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` file at the top?

Comment: Maybe try going back with some other versions of mpdf like `v7.1.7` will help you

Comment: @skndrkhtr5 and its possible to downgrade from 8.0 to 7.1.7 '/vendor/autoload.php'; this code is loaded in artisan file.

Comment: Yes it is, whatever version is defined in the composer.json file for example `"mpdf/mpdf": "^7.1.7"` will update your `vendor/package` after running `composer update` but make sure to backup `composer.json` before doing this, you might face some issues because it will update your other packages too.

Comment: @skndrkhtr5 many thanks

Comment: What does "does not work" mean exactly? What do you have in your error logs? Or what is the behaviour that make you think that it "does not work"? It doesn't make sense to solve such issue without communication the error in detail.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\public\info.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\public\info.php on line 6